# Redirect all URLs that end in .php to no extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need your help.

I would like to redirect all files in a *specific folder* to redirect from .php to no extension. I tried to change htaccess, but it does not work. I only want the files in the hotels folder to be redirected. I have not yet found a proper solution here at stackoverflow .

> mysite.com/hotels/london.php  &
>
> mysite.com/hotels/new-york.php

to

> mysite.com/hotels/london  &
>
> mysite.com/hotels/new-york

What would be the appropriate redirect so that if someone clicks one of the .php URLs, they are redirected to the extension-less URL. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Hint: you need to make use of `.htaccess`

Comment: @Thamilan That would only be a possible solution in case of an Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

make sure mod_rewrite installed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried, but it does not work. Do you have any suggestions?